# Facelets: How to save properties to the view bean?

Tags: java, facelets

The question maybe too simple and stupid, however, I didn't get any useful information from google.

The bean class:

```
public class Foo {

    boolean a;

    public boolean getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(boolean a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

}
```

And the page:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{foo.a}" />
```

Instead of a valueChangeListener, how can I write back the value of the checkbox to the "a" property in the view bean? Or generally, What's the recommended way to update the bean properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to submit the form. Do this with a `<h:commandButton />`, for example. Make sure that both tags are within the same `<h:form></h:form>`.

Generally speaking, every `<h:commandSomething` that has no `immediate="true"` attribute, will submit the form (and let the values of input fields go through conversion, validation and bean update).